# How many British and British affiliated Indians lost their lives in the Indian freedom struggle?

Tags: india, british-empire, colonial

There is a lot of material on how many Indians lost their lives, killed or missing in the British colonial era.
But how many people affiliated to the East India Company and later, the British Empire lost their lives in the process?

Edit :
There are many resources when it comes to the stories and casualties of Indian freedom fighters. There is some secondary data on how many British Captains and Magistrates were murdered, specially in Bengal and Punjab regions. But till date, I have not come across any study that compiles the casualties of British citizens and/or servants of the Crown. While there is such data available for World Wars, no such data is available in Indian context. Beyond that, I am not sure how else to phrase it. If this is insufficient, I will remove the questions and post it later with details.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: There are many resources when it comes to the stories and casualties of Indian freedom fighters. There is some secondary data on how many British Captains and Magistrates were murdered, specially in Bengal and Punjab regions. But till date, I have not come across any study that compiles the casualties of British citizens and/or servants of the Crown. 
While there is such data available for World Wars, no such data is available in Indian context. 
Beyond that, I am not sure how else to phrase it. If this is insufficient, I will remove the questions and post it later with details.